# Flutter Web - TextFormField disable copy and paste

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield, flutter-web

I want to disable the copy and paste functionality on my textfield but unfortunately it didn't work as expected on the **web**. I tried the following `enableInteractiveSelection` and `toolbarOptions` but still I can copy and paste on the textfield in the web. Whats the solution for this. Thanks

```
  TextFormField(
    enableInteractiveSelection: false,
    toolbarOptions: ToolbarOptions(
      copy: false,
      paste: false,
      cut: false,
      selectAll: false,
    ),
  )
```

Comment: If you use ```TextField``` instead, will ```enableInteractiveSelection``` work ?

Comment: `toolbarOptions` is those options you would see when you tap-hold/long-tap on a TextField. So setting the `toolbarOptions` property does not really disable the copy paste function, its just removing the options to copy, paste, etc from the toolbar.

Comment: @ikerfah yes, still same result it didnt work on web

Comment: @Wahyu I know the interaction on the textfield. I was hoping it would work on web. Is there a work around? Maybe wrapping it with LogicalKeyboardKey and disable from there?

Comment: Do you want to disable the copy, paste, etc functions for the whole page? Then I think its possible by creating a javascript code to disable those functions, and put it in your index.html file, using `<script>` tag.

Comment: @Wahyu, No not the whole page. Lets assume i have 3 textfield and I want only 1 textfield has the disabled copy, paste etc.

Comment: Sorry then, cant help, since I'm not familiar with flutter web :(

Answer (score 4):

If you are considering of shortcut keyboards, we need to listen `LogicalKeySet`.

**Result**

[image]

I've done this way:

**For copy-paste keys**

```
///* for mac replace  LogicalKeyboardKey.control, with LogicalKeyboardKey.meta
final selectableKeySetwindows = LogicalKeySet(
  LogicalKeyboardKey.control,
  LogicalKeyboardKey.keyA,
);
final pasteKeySetwindows = LogicalKeySet(
  LogicalKeyboardKey.control,
  LogicalKeyboardKey.keyV,
);

/// i dont have any ios device ,let me know what it produce.
final selectableKeySetMac = LogicalKeySet(
  LogicalKeyboardKey.meta,
  LogicalKeyboardKey.keyA,
);
```

```
class SelectionIntent extends Intent {}

class PasteIntent extends Intent {}
```

**The widget that will handle Events**

```
class DisableShortcut extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;

  const DisableShortcut({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FocusableActionDetector(
      shortcuts: {
        selectableKeySetwindows: SelectionIntent(),
        pasteKeySetwindows: PasteIntent(),
      },
      actions: {
        SelectionIntent: CallbackAction(
          onInvoke: (intent) {
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Copy is forbidden")));
            return FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
          },
        ),
        PasteIntent: CallbackAction(
          onInvoke: (intent) async {
            // ClipboardData? data = await Clipboard.getData('text/plain');
            // print(" paste callBack ${data!.text}");
            return ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Paste is forbidden")));
          },
        )
      },
      autofocus: true,
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

**My testWidget**

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            TextField(),
            TextField(),
            DisableShortcut(
              child: TextField(
                enableInteractiveSelection: false,
                toolbarOptions: ToolbarOptions(
                  copy: false,
                  cut: false,
                  paste: false,
                  selectAll: false,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```