# Prevent copy paste feature when right click the mouse in textfields flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I prevent copy paste in textformfield(Flutter web) using Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V by adding

```dart
enableInteractiveSelection: false,
toolbarOptions: ToolbarOptions(
  copy: false,
  cut: false,
  paste: false,
  selectAll: false,
),
```

But still, it is possible to copy-paste by the following method,
[image]

Is it possible to prevent ?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/68185106/4394827

Comment: @HemanthS already tried with that toolbar option

Comment: Same thread has accepted answer what about that

Comment: please try to se this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68688646/flutter-web-textformfield-disable-copy-and-paste

Answer (score 2, accepted):

work around is, if user right click on textfield, unfocus, or even disable it:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return SizedBox(
          width: 300,
          child: Listener(
            onPointerDown: (event){
              if(event.kind == PointerDeviceKind.mouse && event.buttons == kSecondaryMouseButton){
                print('yoo the user try to right click unfocus this so he cant paste');
                _focusNode.unfocus();
              }
            },
            child: TextField(
              enableInteractiveSelection: false,
              toolbarOptions: ToolbarOptions(
                paste: false
              ),
              onChanged: (data){
                print(data);
              },
              focusNode: _focusNode,
              controller: _textEditingController,
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Added the below code in index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.oncontextmenu = new Function('return false')
    document.body.oncut = new Function('return false');
    document.body.oncopy = new Function('return false');
    document.body.onpaste = new Function('return false');
</script>
```

It will prevent right click of mouse.